# Route traffic to particular server based on URL path on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: wordpress, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudflare

This is just an idea in the making right now so no specifics but, I am wondering what the best way to route traffic to a particular server for URLs with the path /post*?

I am running a WordPress/WooCommerce install on ElasticBeanstalk which is all setup already but I am thinking of adding a blog to the site. This would all be under the same application and deployment etc (so normal WP site really, just write a post and publish on the same site) but I want to ensure users viewing the blog area of the site don't consume resources for the eCommerce side.

If the blog runs slow at a given time this is not a huge issue but the eCommerce side shouldn't be hindered by a spike in CPU for example.

My initial thought is to have a separate EC2 that accepts traffic to all blog related paths but how could this link into git/application deployments via AWS etc? Maybe there is an easier approach I'm missing?

The current setup is basically the below:

- CloudFlare for DNS
- WP on ElasticBeanstalk with autoscaling/loadbalancer
- AL2 with NGINX
- Worker application for background task (no webserver) also ELB
- Shared RDS instance for DB
- EFS for ephemeral storage
- S3 for storage

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this as a single Elastic Beanstalk deployment. Elastic Beanstalk is for running a single app. You would need to have a 2nd Elastic Beanstalk deployment for your blog application. You would configure path routing rules in Cloudflare to forward requests to `/blog/*` to the new server.